# Need help to create sql query MySQLi PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two tables
COMPANY: company_id, company_name 
REVIEW: review_id, company_id, review_text

I am trying to make search functional on site. I try to display all reviews of specific company. Example, I have search field, I enter there "Microsoft" and then I need all reviews about Microsoft.

I try to do such query, but it is not working

```
            $company_name = $_POST["company_name"] ?? '';
            $review_text = $_POST["review_text"] ?? '';
            $searchc = $_POST["searchc"] ?? '';


            if(isset($_POST['show'])){
                $result2 = $mysqli->prepare(
                    "SELECT review_text
                   FROM review
                   WHERE company_id
                   IN (HERE I THINK I NEED EMBED QUERY... BUT NOT SURE..) ?");
                $result2->bind_param("s", $searchc);
                $result2->execute();
                $result2->store_result();
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
            }

            <div class="right">
                <form method="post">
                    <br/>
                    <input name="searchc" type="text" value=""><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="show" name="show">

                  </form>


                    Text: <?=$row2['review_text']?><br />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a SQL join on your tables

```
$sql = "SELECT review.*, company.company_name
        FROM review
        INNER JOIN company ON review.company_id = company.company_id WHERE 
        company.company_name = ?";
$result2->bind_param("s", $searchc);
```

Comment: Please update your answer with bind variable syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me. In my code I used this - $result2 = $mysqli->prepare( ... I tried to add your query sql to prepare, but not working

Comment: [05-Jul-2017 11:30:44 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: row2 in /home/asd/public_html/asd/test/index.php on line 94

[05-Jul-2017 11:30:49 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/asd/public_html/asd/test/index.php on line 52

[05-Jul-2017 11:30:49 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /home/asd/public_html/asd/test/index.php on line 55

Answer (score 1):

You will need a nested query like this:

```
$result2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT review_text FROM review WHERE company_id 
IN (SELECT company_id from company where company_name=?");
$result2 = bind_param("s", $searchc);
$result2->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform a `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT review_text
                   FROM review
                  JOIN  COMPANY on review.company_id = COMPANY.company_id;
```

Well, in case you are getting company name as input then you are almost close

```
SELECT review_text
                   FROM review
                   WHERE company_id
                   IN (select company_id from company where company_name = $company_name)
```

Comment: He doesnt have a company ID from user input

Comment: Yes query looks good, but if i try to use it in my code it is not working... My codes uses placeholders ?? '', may be this is a reason?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    REVIEW.*, COMPANY.company_name
FROM
    REVIEW
INNER JOIN COMPANY ON REVIEW.company_id = COMPANY.company_id
WHERE
    COMPANY.company_name = "$search";
```

Results with $search = 'Apple':

```
"4" "2" "Apple Review 1"    "Apple"
"5" "2" "Apple Review 2"    "Apple"
"6" "2" "Apple Review 3"    "Apple"
```

Try this:

```
SELECT
    REVIEW.*, COMPANY.company_name
FROM
    REVIEW
INNER JOIN COMPANY ON REVIEW.company_id = COMPANY.company_id
WHERE
    COMPANY.company_name = "$search";
```

Results with $search = 'Apple':

```
"4" "2" "Apple Review 1"    "Apple"
"5" "2" "Apple Review 2"    "Apple"
"6" "2" "Apple Review 3"    "Apple"
```

**`EDIT 1:`**
I use PostgreSQL, the only difference in what I am going to show you, is when you create the tables and insert the data. The SQL statement to do what you need is the same.

First, create the 2 tables `company` and `review`

```
CREATE TABLE company
(
  company_id integer NOT NULL,
  company_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (company_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE company
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And review table:

```
CREATE TABLE review
(
  review_id integer NOT NULL,
  company_id integer NOT NULL,
  review_text character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT review_pkey PRIMARY KEY (review_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE review
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

After having created the tables, insert data in them. For your problem I use the following...

```
Company Table:
-----------------------------
company_id  |   company_name
-----------------------------
|   1       |   Microsoft   |
|   2       |   Apple       |
|   3       |   NASA        |
-----------------------------
```

And review table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
review_id   |   company_id  |   review_text         |
----------------------------|------------------------
|   1       |   1           |   Microsoft Review 1  |
|   2       |   1           |   Microsoft Review 2  |
|   3       |   1           |   Microsoft Review 3  |
|   4       |   2           |   Apple Review 1      |
|   5       |   2           |   Apple Review 2      |
|   6       |   2           |   Apple Review 3      |
|   7       |   3           |   NASA Review 1       |
|   8       |   3           |   NASA Review 2       |
|   9       |   3           |   NASA Review 3       |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

After this, you can check the output of the following SQL statement with your SQL administrator (Navicat, MySQL Workbench or whatever you use) ...
New SQL query and you write:

```
SELECT
    review.*, company.company_name
FROM
    review
INNER JOIN company ON review.company_id = company.company_id
WHERE
    company.company_name = 'Apple';
```

and the output will be...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
review_id   |   company_id  |   review_text         |   company_name|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|"4"        |   "2"         |   "Apple Review 1"    |"Apple"        |
|"5"        |   "2"         |   "Apple Review 2"    |"Apple"        |
|"6"        |   "2"         |   "Apple Review 3"    |"Apple"        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To use that SQL statement in your PHP code, it is simple ...

```
$result2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
    review.*, company.company_name
FROM
    review
INNER JOIN company ON review.company_id = company.company_id
WHERE
    company.company_name = $company_name");
```

....

Comment: First off, there is no way that works in the way you described it without LIKE.  Second that syntax isn't going to work with PHP.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I use this query using my code? If I add this sql query instead mine, it is not working, probably because I use php7 and placeholders and bind function?

Comment: Thank you, but nope...not working ... here is my (your) php code. Have a look please ..
            if(isset($_POST['show'])){
                $result2 = $mysqli->prepare(
                    "SELECT review.*, company.company_name
        FROM review
        INNER JOIN company ON review.company_id = 
    company.company_id WHERE 
        company.company_name = '$searchc'");
                $result2->bind_param("s", $searchc);
                $result2->execute();
                $result2->store_result();
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
            }

Comment: First, execute the SQL statement in your SQL administrator, to verify if it returns the expected result, you can also post the error that returns you when you use it in your PHP code, perhaps, can help me to understand that you are doing wrong.